# vue-test-utils: mocking vue-router and vuex in the same test

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I'm trying to mount a component that uses Vuex and requires $route.query to be mocked

```
import { mount, shallow, createLocalVue } from 'vue-test-utils'
import Vue from 'vue'
import expect from 'expect'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import Post from '../../components/Post.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex);
localVue.use(VueRouter);

describe('Lead list', () => {
    let wrapper;
    let getters;
    let store;

    beforeEach(() => {

        getters = {
            post: () => { return {} }
        }
        store = new Vuex.Store({
            getters
        });

    });


    it('should just be true', () => {

        const $route = {
            path: '/some/path',
            query: {}
        }

        wrapper = shallow(Post, {
            localVue,
            mocks: {
                $route
            }, store
        });

        expect(true).toBe(true);

    });
});
```

And I'm getting back this error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property $route of #<VueComponent> which has only a getter
```

I've found the closed issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/142 that has similar error. But my case is a little different. If I remove store or mocks from the options it works fine, but it does't work when you have both. Is this an issue or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting this error because you have installed VueRouter on the Vue constructor, by calling `localVue.use(VueRouter)`. This adds $route as a read only property on the localVue constructor.

You're then trying to overwrite `$router` using `mocks`. `mocks` is unable to overwrite `$route` because it's been added as a read only property by Vue Router.

To fix your problem, you could create another `localVue`, install Vuex, and then use `mocks` to pass in `$route`:

```
it('should just be true', () => {
  const freshLocalVue = createLocalVue()
  freshLocalVue.use(Vuex)
  const $route = {
    path: '/some/path',
    query: {}
  }

  wrapper = shallow(Post, {
      localVue,
      mocks: {
          $route
      }, 
      store
  })

  expect(true).toBe(true)
})
```

Comment: I managed to make it work by using `freshLocalVue.use(VueRouter)` instead of Vuex. But you definitely pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I can't get this to work. Either there's a router, and $route can't be mocked, or there's no router and I get tons of errors because the code depends on a router. I don't understand the design decision that $route can't be mocked.

Comment: this works but without `freshLocalVue.use(VueRouter)` I get warnings about unknown custom element `<router-link>`. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: @r_zelazny regarding the unknown `router-link`, see the [vue-test-utils docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vue-router.html#using-stubs). You can basically stub them by adding `stubs: ['router-link', 'router-view']` to your shallowMount/mount properties.